# Best approach to load multiple native libraries in Android App

Tags: java, android, jar, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have an app which makes use of 3 different JAR libraries...lets call them a.jar, b.jar and c.jar.
Each of these JARS have an accompanied native C++ shared object.

Now, both a.jar and b.jar import and use c.jar.

So, my question is - what is the best approach when loading the native libs using system.loadLibrary ?
Can I just load them all from my app code or do they have to be loaded by the respective JAR ?
If I load them from the respective JAR file, will load in a separate thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Classes' responsibility to load native libraries.

Let's assume every jar file also has classes called A, B and C. All those classes needs to load their native companions most probably via a static way.

```
class A { 
    static { 
        System.loadLibrary(“A”); 
    }

    C c;
} 

class C { 
     static { 
         System.loadLibrary(“C”); 
     }
}
```

In such structure it will be the class loader who loads and initialize class C when you access class A.

Comment: Thanks.  And, since its static, Library C is only loaded once...even if class B also instantiates class C.  Being in separate JAR files, would they share the address space ?

Comment: Of course, being in separate JARs only shows how they lay in disk. A single JVM instance always runs in a single address space.